# Is there any generic method of showing existence on quasilinear pde?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Is there any method on second (or higher) order quasilinear pde that can show local (or global) existence on quasilinear pde not by solving the problem analytically, which works on many different types of pdes?

Comment: Cauchy-Kowalevskaya? Method of characteristics?

Comment: @CalvinKhor - Does that(the second one;first one I know it can't) explain "pdes that is not of first order"? Besides, the first one is clearly an answer...yeah, I should have added the condition that the order is not 1.

Comment: probably not....